# Why is X-axis not scaling to the data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, axis

(Novice and almost entirely self-taught, but can't seem to find anything here that addresses my issue)
I am adding a chart to a spreadsheet that tracks outstanding tasks for each day by type. I am using dates as horizontal labels. However, I wish to omit weekends and holidays, but want to include days I do not receive the data as empty cells *e.g* 12/04.
I have the range with the desired dates as the top row of my spreadsheet. The problem is that, if I choose the axis to be "Date Axis", I get this: (with weekends/holidays included, even though they are not in the source range.)
[With date axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11sFu.png)
But if I use a "Text Axis" I get this: (axis not running the length of the plot area)
[with text axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTiyL.png)
I can't figure out why the axis isn't scaling with the width of the chart area.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your post and add the sample data that produced both charts. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, stumbled into an answer that makes no sense, but works. Posting because, eventually, someone will run into the same problem.
My date labels are in $C$1:$X$1, which is 23 cells. I had to change  the X-axis to a date axis, then give it the range 12/01/2020 to 12/23/2020, then change BACK to a text axis.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is best to use a "Text Axis", you may enter the date as your needs manually. If you use "Date Axis", two days of the weekend would shown on the chart, it seems to be an expected behavior.

If you create a table, then insert a Line chart based on this table, every time you enter the date and the corresponding data at the bottom of the table, the value would be added into the table and the chart automatically.